# Getting warning "May not respond to animetedTextField:up" for following code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Below is my code to make the textfield visible when keyboard is up.
Now, it's working fine with the code. However, Giving me warning that may not respond to animateTextField:up. can any1 please help me to remove this warning?

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
}
- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    int animatedDistance;
    int moveUpValue = textField.frame.origin.y+ textField.frame.size.height;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {

        animatedDistance = 216-(460-moveUpValue-5);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = 162-(320-moveUpValue-5);
    }

    if(animatedDistance>0)
    {
        const int movementDistance = animatedDistance;
        const float movementDuration = 0.3f; 
        int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);
        [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);       
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare your `- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up` method in your @implementation .h file

or

move that `animateTextField` function ***above*** your `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method so the compiler sees it before it hits that function.

Answer (score 2):

Put an empty category in `.m` file and declare your method in `@interface`.

```
@interface TheClass ()

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up;

@end
```